# Build times out, can't increase time out

Tags: google-cloud-build

I'm deploying to Kubernettes via Cloud Build. Every now and then the build times out because it exceeds the build-in time out of ten minutes. I can't figure out how to increase this time out. I'm using in-line build config in my trigger. It looks like this

```
    steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - $_DOCKERFILE_NAME
    dir: $_DOCKERFILE_DIR
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy
    args:
      - prepare
      - '--filename=$_K8S_YAML_PATH'
      - '--image=$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--app=$_K8S_APP_NAME'
      - '--version=$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--namespace=$_K8S_NAMESPACE'
      - '--label=$_K8S_LABELS'
      - '--annotation=$_K8S_ANNOTATIONS,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID'
      - '--create-application-cr'
      - >-
        --links="Build
        details=https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/$BUILD_ID?project=$PROJECT_ID"
      - '--output=output'
    id: Prepare deploy
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |-
        if [ "$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH" != "" ]
        then
          gsutil cp -r output/suggested gs://$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH/config/$_K8S_APP_NAME/$BUILD_ID/suggested
          gsutil cp -r output/expanded gs://$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH/config/$_K8S_APP_NAME/$BUILD_ID/expanded
        fi
    id: Save configs
    entrypoint: sh
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy
    args:
      - apply
      - '--filename=output/expanded'
      - '--cluster=$_GKE_CLUSTER'
      - '--location=$_GKE_LOCATION'
      - '--namespace=$_K8S_NAMESPACE'
    id: Apply deploy
    timeout: 900s
images:
  - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
substitutions:
  _K8S_NAMESPACE: default
  _OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx_cloudbuild/deploy
  _K8S_YAML_PATH: kubernetes/
  _DOCKERFILE_DIR: ''
  _IMAGE_NAME: xxxxxxxxxxx
  _K8S_ANNOTATIONS: gcb-trigger-id=xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx
  _GKE_CLUSTER: xxxxx
  _K8S_APP_NAME: xxxxx
  _DOCKERFILE_NAME: Dockerfile
  _K8S_LABELS: ''
  _GKE_LOCATION: xxxxxxxx
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy
  - $_K8S_APP_NAME
```

I've tried sticking the `timeout: 900` arg in in various places with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout of 10 minutes is the default for the [whole build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2), therefore if you add the `timeout: 900s` option in any of the [steps](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#buildstep), it will only apply to the step that it has been added to. You can make a step have a larger timeout than the overall build timeout, but the whole build process will fail if the sum of all the steps exceeds the build timeout. This example shows this behavior:

```
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['sleep', '600']
  timeout: 800s # Step timeout -> Allows the step to run up to 800s, but as the overall timeout is 600s, it will fail after that time has been passed, so the effective timeout value is 600s.
timeout: 600s # Overall build timeout
```

That said, the solution is to expand the overall build timeout by adding it outside of any step, and then you can have a build with up to 24h to finish before it fails with a timeout error.

Something like the following example should work out for you:

```
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['sleep', '600']
timeout: 3600s
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to use a high-end machine so that overall it takes less time in the build process.

You can specify it like

```yaml
options:
  machineType: N1_HIGHCPU_8
```

Note: This performance benefits come at a cost. Please look into the pricing section to use optimal machine as per your requirement and budget.